# Why is porridge easy to digest?

Tags: diet

What's the reasons that support the point that porridge is easy to digest ? Why a sick person is advised to eat porridge instead of rice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason porridge is thought of as an easy to digest food, is that it has no large pieces for the body's digestive system to have to process. Just like eating mashed potatoes vs. home fries, or yogurt vs. cottage cheese. You don't even need to CHEW porridge. It just slides on down.

As far as providing much nutrition, though, that's the catch. Depending on what you make the porridge from, you may be just getting some carbs and empty calories.

It would be much better to give a sick person a really nutrition-packed shake, smoothie, or blended soup. Or, at least stir a scoop or two of powdered greens and protein into the porridge to boost it's nutritional profile.

Comment: It also traditionally has a fairly high fiber content, which may contribute to it being easily processed, although a casual Google search reveals that a number of people also have gas issues from the fiber.